# Trying to put a posted php variable into a javascript variable so can plot on googlemap

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, variables, post

Hi I have posted two values for latitute and longitute to a php page using a form, then on the php page I am displaying a googlemap and want to use the two values i posted as the latitude and longitute to plot on the map. I think iv done everything right but it doesnt seem to pick up the values.any ideas? cheers!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {


var lat= "<?php echo $_POST['coordinates']; ?>";
var long= "<?php echo $_POST['coordinatestwo']; ?>";



var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: "Your current location!"
        });

        }


   </script>

   </head>
   <body onLoad="initialize();">
```

Answer (score 1):

`long` is a reserved word in JavaScript.  Try `lng` (no 'o') as your variable name instead.

```
var lng= "<?php echo $_POST['coordinatestwo']; ?>";
```

If you `view source` in your browser, do you see the php values there?  If not then there is something wrong with your form. We would need to see more code.

But chances are it's the `long` being a reserved word issue I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `long` as a variable name (it's a [reserved word](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm)). Also, you don't need quotes around numeric values. Try this:

```
var lat = <?php echo floatval($_POST['coordinates']); ?>;
var lng = <?php echo floatval($_POST['coordinatestwo']); ?>;
```

**EDIT**: Tip - if you use a (good) editor with color highlighting and syntax checking for JavaScript, this is an error that would be highlighted (mine reports: "*strict warning: long is a reserver identifier*").

Comment: Cheers i tried making those changes but still seems to not pick them up. had a look at source and right enough the two values both equal 0. here is the form im using: 


   <div>
   <form name="hitcherform"action="results.php" method="post">
   <label for="destination">Where you going?</label>
   <input id="destination" name="destination" type="text" />
   <input type="hidden" id="coordinates" name="coordinates" type="text" />
   <input type="hidden" id="coordinatestwo" name="coordinatestwo" type="text" />
   <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" />
   </form>
   </div>

Comment: @paul elliot, then probably your $_POST variables don't contain what you expect them to. Try using `print_r($_POST);` to see what's really in there!

Answer (score 0):

I have a working jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/RFHKd/

Mostly your code. I added the following:

1. A 'div' with an ID of map_canvas
2. A style to this div giving it width and height.
3. Included the script to load google maps.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

@paul elliot: That doesn't look like all your code..? See this example to fill in the bits your code is missing: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html